# Modifying error and log messages on fly

Tags: bash, shell

I have a situation wherein I want to send error and log messages to a same file. To distinguish between the error and log messages I am appending the log messages like this :

file would look like this :

```
===============log_and_error_msg.txt =========
ERR: This message is an error message
INF: This is a log message
```

so that anybody interested in error messages can `grep "ERR" log_and_error_msg.txt`

suppose I am executing some shell script like this

```
./shellscript 2>>log_and_error_msg.txt 1>>log_and_error_msg.txt
```

How do I add ERR and INF on fly to each message on fly ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed. Insert `sed 's/^/TYPE /'` in each pipeline, replacing TYPE with `ERR:` or `INF:`

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3> >(sed 's/^/INF: /' >> prepend.log)
exec 4> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /' >> prepend.log)
echo "some information" >&3
echo "an error" >&4
echo "more information" >&3
echo "this goes to the screen"
echo "this goes to stderr, bypassing the log" >&2
echo "another error" >&4
echo "yet more information" >&3
echo "still information" >&3
echo "oops" >&4
```

Comment: +1 nice demonstration of `exec` redirection and process substitution

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting stderr to a temporary file.

```
./testscript.sh 2> err.tmp | ( while read line ; do echo 'INFO: ' $line ; done ) ; ( while read line ; do echo 'ERR: ' $line ; done ) <err.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ { ./shellscript | sed 's/^/INF: /'; } 2>&1 1>&3 | sed 's/^/ERR: /'; } \
>> log_and_error_message.txt 3>&1
```